# hub_distance in python standalone script

Tags: pyqgis, csv, qgis-processing

I need to load geometry from csv and then use it to calculate hub distance. I write the following script, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
 sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/')
 from processing.core.Processing import Processing
 from processing.tools import *
 qgs = QgsApplication([], True)

 QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)

 Processing.initialize()
 QgsApplication.initQgis()
 layer = QgsVectorLayer('from_excel.csv', 'from_excel', "delimitedtext")

 layer.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(32365, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId))



layer2 = QgsVectorLayer('/home/raven/work/UpWork/Inputs/Cenefas.shp', 'Cenefas', 'ogr')
layer2.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(32365, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId))

general.runalg("qgis:distancetonearesthub", layer, layer2, 'test', 0, 0, 'HubOutput')

QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

Then I've bunch or errors:

1. Warning: Not all input layers use the same CRS.
2. Fields of width 255 truncated to 254 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'boundingBox'
3. Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a few issues:

1. I think you need to replace `qgs = QgsApplication([], True)` with `qgs = QApplication([], True)`.
2. When loading a csv file, you need to set the relevant parameters such as the `delimiter` and (assuming you want to load it as a point layer) set the `X` `Y` fields. However, I found that calling this point layer into the algorithm fails as the path of the file also contains those settings. So perhaps it is best to import the csv as a layer and export this to a shapefile. Then call this shapefile into the algorithm.
3. I don't think `EPSG:32365` exists, was this a typo?

---

The following code works for me using `EPSG:27700` (note that I tested this on QGIS 2.18.2 for Windows 7 64-bit, you can adjust the paths accordingly):

```
qgs = QApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/')
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
from processing.tools import *
Processing.initialize()

uri = '/home/raven/work/UpWork/Inputs/from_excel.csv?delimiter=,&crs=epsg:27700&xField=x&yField=y'
point_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'from_excel', 'delimitedtext')
point_path = '/home/raven/work/UpWork/Inputs/point.shp'
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(point_layer, point_path, "utf-8", None, "ESRI Shapefile")

layer = QgsVectorLayer(point_path, 'point', 'ogr')

layer2 = QgsVectorLayer('/home/raven/work/UpWork/Inputs/Cenefas.shp', 'Cenefas', 'ogr')
layer2.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(27700, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId))

general.runalg("qgis:distancetonearesthub", layer, layer2, 'test', 0, 0, 'HubOutput')

QgsApplication.exitQgis()
qgs.exit()
```

Comment: Joseph, thank your for answer, but anyway I've bunch of errors:
Warning: Not all input layers use the same CRS.
This can cause unexpected results.
Warning 1: Field HubName of width 255 truncated to 254.
float division by zero
See log for more details
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @АлександрЗахаров - If you want to perform spatial analysis, the layers should already be reprojected to the correct CRS. Setting the CRS as you did in your code will not reproject the data which probably explains why you keep getting the CRS warning. Either load the layer in QGIS and use the `Save As...` option to save it as a new shapefile with the new CRS or use the `general.runalg("qgis:reprojectlayer")` algorithm in your code. The field HubName warning can be ignored, not sure about the segmentation fault. Try commenting out `QgsApplication.exitQgis()` and `qgs.exit()`.